# Are [dynamic-web-controls] that helpful? (seeking expertise of C#/ASP.NET developers)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[dynamic-web-controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-web-controls) had just 14 questions, in half of them the tag wasn't helpful at all, so I edited those to remove/substitute the tag; [other 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-web-controls) (now 3 left, see comments) are related to C#/ASP.NET and the most recent one is back from 2015. The tag has no description, no usage guidance, so I wonder, should it be burninated? (I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, so can't be so sure)

The check-list:

1. The tag is rather ambiguous.. or just too broad (like [frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend))
2. The tag concept is on-topic
3. Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post? I doubt: ASP.NET is for web pages which almost always contain some controls, isn't it? This is something where I lack expertise
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? In the context of web, this is a very vague thing. What "dynamic" means? Generated with JavaScript? With back-end? Behaves dynamically in some aspect? I don't think it means the same.. unless somebody annotates it properly (may be in context of ASP.NET this term has some special meaning?)

So it seems to me, it definitely should be annotated or burninated.

Comment: If it is about ASP.NET server-controls could be meant in which case we have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-server-controls or the kind of related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxcontroltoolkit if nobody else chimes in I might go over those remaining ones and moderate them accordingly.

Comment: @rene 7 questions... yes moderate away no one will miss that tag

Comment: A quick scan reveals that all questions are about "generating serverside controls at runtime". These don't have to be custom controls, it could be buttons. Just nuke the tag. I've removed it from a question where it didn't apply at all.

Comment: ok, reviewed and untagged 3 more questions, closed one of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between [YakovL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3995261/yakovl), [CodeCaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) and myself we've removed the tag from all questions.

Given no one uses it on a question again before 03:00 UTC the tag will be gone.